# Convert Excel File to PDF using Matlab while ignoring scale

Tags: excel, matlab, pdf

I want to convert an Excel File into a PDF using Matlab. The Excel File is filled with a table and a graphic. They take a space larger than a DIN A4 page, so when i use following code, my Excel-File is 'divided' on several pages in the PDF. I would like to ask, if and how it is possible to scale the Output in the PDF on one page, or ignoring the scale, so that perhaps the table is totally on one page and the graphic underneath. Perhaps changing the printing properties to only one page would help. Is it possible to do this in Matlab?

The code:

```
hExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
hWorkbook = hExcel.Workbooks.Open(sprintf('%s', 'C:\test.xls'));
hWorksheet = hWorkbook.Sheets.Item('Test');
hWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat('xlTypePDF', 'C:\test_out.pdf');
```

I looked up the ExportAsFixedFormat on Microsoft Help, but everything else I tried on changing, won't work and I get error messages. I tried e.g.:

```
hExcel = actxserver('Excel.Application');
hWorkbook = hExcel.Workbooks.Open(sprintf('%s', 'C:\test.xls'));
hWorksheet = hWorkbook.Sheets.Item('Test');
hWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat('xlTypePDF', 'C:\test_out.pdf', 'xlQualityStandard', true, true);`
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code I recorded using a macro recording.
If this is not working properly, just go and record your own pagesetup macro before you saving as a PDF.
[image]

Page setup all the pages

```
Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")).Select
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.784313725490196)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.784313725490196)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.980392156862745)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.980392156862745)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.509803921568628)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.509803921568628)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 100
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 100
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = ""
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.236220472440945)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.748031496062992)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.31496062992126)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .Draft = False
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 0
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

To save as PDF

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, fName & ".pdf", _
 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
 IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
 OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, predefining page makeup works fine with my wishes. But I was looking for a code to use in matlab, that does these steps automatically. Perhaps I should edit my question a bit.

Comment: Not an expert of Matlab coding. Sorry I couldn't help.